# JSF Dropdown / SelectItem not working?

Tags: java, jsf, drop-down-menu

Ok trying to use JSF dropdown menu. I did the following which follows what others post or generally in the internet..

```
<td>

                <h:selectOneMenu id="purposeOption"
                required="true"
                value="#{formData.requestType}">
                <f:selectItem
                    itemValue="#{formData.projectOption}"
                    itemLabel="Project"/>
                <f:selectItem
                    itemValue="#{formData.trainingOption}"
                    itemLabel="Training"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
 </td>
```

Dont understand why it displays blank space next to request type in the next page.

```
Request Type: #{formBean.requestType}
```

any hints?

Comment: What is the scope of your `formData` bean?

Comment: You have written `#{formBean.requestType}`, shouldn't it be `#{formData.requestType}`?

Comment: Sorry that's on my part mistake....all formData has been converted to formBean...so just assume now that all are formBean.

Comment: nope I have no idea what that means though :(

Comment: @Hari when i did, all other fields shows blank :((

Comment: after messing with it, i get this:

j_idt7:purposeOption: Validation Error: Value is required.

Comment: So you are selecting a value from the drop down and trying to print the selected value in the next page. But the value which selected had selected is replaced with the space. is this the issue u are trying to say ?

Comment: It is already fixed Hari in the answer below :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

```
       <td>

                <h:selectOneMenu id="purposeOption"
                required="true"
                value="#{formBean.requestType}">
                <f:selectItem
                    itemValue="Project"
                    itemLabel="Project"/>
                <f:selectItem
                    itemValue="Training"
                    itemLabel="Training"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
```